# Does the level name "Impale Sticky" in "World of Goo" mean anything?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"World of Goo" is an indie puzzle game. Here's this level's [description](http://worldofgoo.wikia.com/wiki/Impale_Sticky).

I've already asked this question [here](https://www.englishforums.com/English/WhatDoesImpaleStickyMean/bhjxlp/post.htm), but I'm still not satisfied with answers. Of course, I have checked these two words in various dictionaries. Maybe this is some kind of a strange reference? Also, the word order seems strange to me, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I doubt there's a single authoritative answer for this; the name sounds like it was chosen for just a sort of general feel, without much precision, so unless there's documentation of the thought process the developers went through, it's probably going to have to be left vague.

Answer (score 1):

There are flying blades in this level that destroy the "Goo" when touched.  Those flying blades can impale (stab/run through) your goo balls, thus destroying them.  Because goo is sticky and because the swords can kill them, "Impale Sticky" is a play on words to let you know that there are things that will kill your goo balls.

For a bit more info, impale is a bit stronger of a word than stab, though run through is probably a synonym.  When implaled, you rarely survive.  When stabbed, you can usually continue to fight.  Impaling was also a very cruel form of capital punishment with links to Vlad the Impaler and thus to Dracula (thanks to a certain author who played with history a bit.)

Comment: Thx! But what parts of speech is this title made of? Is it a noun "impale" + an adverb "sticky"? I was also asking about the word order. I don't know why, but "Sticky Impale" sounds more "natural" (I'm not a native speaker, of course) to me.

Comment: @user20618 - A level name is not required to be a complete sentence. Technically, this is not, since the verb "impale" has no subject, unless you want to name a Goo ball "Sticky". In that case the phrase becomes an imperative to an unnamed subject. But really, this is reading far too much into a fluffy bit of fun.

Comment: Vlad the Impaler has nothing to do with Dracula. It's just Bram Stoker's invention.

Comment: Yes, very true, but in pop culture they are now linked.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast So "Sticky" means how "impaling" should be done in this imperative, right?

Comment: Who knows?  But I took at as a different name for the goo balls - as a noun.

Comment: No, "sticky" is either an adjective (normal use) or it might be a nick-name, in the same way "snuffy" can be. See Medal of Honor winner "Snuffy" Smith https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maynard_Harrison_Smith. If it were used to modify "impale" it would be an adverb, and that form already exists: stickily. In this case the phrase would mean (roughly) "You see that goo ball over there? His name is Sticky. Go shove a sword through him."